# Java get elements that are not in an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to add users to a model.
I want to add all the users that are in `MembersArray` but not in `membersAvailableArray`.

> membersAvailableArray = all members in the class.
>   MembersArray = all members

Im trying to get all members that are in `MembersArray` but not `membersAvailableArray`

```
DefaultListModel<String> model2 = new DefaultListModel<>();

       for(Member allMems: MembersArray)
       {
             for(Member mems: membersAvailableArray)
             {

                 if(!allMems.getUsername().equals(mems.getUsername()))
                 {
                     model2.addElement(allMems.getFirstName() + " " + allMems.getLastName());
                 }


             }
       }
       availableMembersJList.setModel(model2);
```

Comment: Where's the question? Also, rather than two foreach loops, you should use a single foreach to loop through the member array and use `ArrayList's` `.contains()` method to check presence in the other list

Comment: it's easier using a Set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need any looping here, just some good old "All" operations:

```
ArrayList<Member> membersToAdd = members.clone();
membersToAdd.removeAll(availableMembers);
```

`membersToAdd` now has all the members you need to add.

---

If you happen to have Java 8, there is an even simpler way to do this:

```
members.stream()
        .filter(p->!availableMembers.contains(p))
        .forEach(p->model2.addElement(p));
```

Comment: Good call on the no looping. I will have to remember that one.

Comment: Great and simple, thank you I knew their had to be a way that was simple.

Answer (score 0):

try this tricky way, add all to an `ArrayList` and remove those you do not want

```
ArrayList<Member> tmp = new ArrayList<Member>();
tmp.addAll(MembersArray);
tmp.removeAll(membersAvailableArray);
for(Member allMems: tmp){
    model2.addElement(allMems.getFirstName() + " " + allMems.getLastName());
}
```